# DB2: How to add new column between existing columns?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I have an existing DB2 database and a table named 
`employee` with columns 
`id,e_name,e_mobile_no,e_dob,e_address`.

How can I add a new column `e_father_name` before `e_mobile_no`?

Comment: I don't think DB2 supports this syntax.  You basically need to create another table.

Comment: yes but it may be possible .

Comment: You can do it in DB2 IBM i 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always do the following --

- Take a backup/dump of table data and db2look
  (If you dump to a CSV file as I do I suggest dumping in the new format  so for example put null for the new column in the right place.
- Drop table and indexes
- Create table with the new colunn
- Load data with old values
- Recreate all indexes and runstats.

Once you have done it a few times it becomes old hat.

Comment: @Mohit I love it! Accepted answer with -1. -- Maybe consider up-voting too?

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the [ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055069.html) procedure which allows to change the table structure.

The [ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html) only allows adding columns to the end of the table. The reason is that it would change the physical structure of the table, i.e., each row would need to be adapted to the new format. This would be quite expensive.

Using the mentioned procedure `ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE` you would copy the entire table and during that process change the table structure. It requires a significant amount of space and time.

Answer (score 2):

In DB2 IBM i v7r1 you can do it, try on your DB2 version

```
alter table yourtable
add column e_father_name varchar(10) before e_mobile_no
```

Comment: DB2 is on multiple system and with multiple version

Comment: @Esperento57 -- the question is tagged DB2-LUW

Comment: Thank you, it was not that it was proposed and that I answered.

Comment: Worked great.  Easier to document the create or replace table.